# Can a Divination Wizard use the Portent feature on themself while blinded?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, conditions

The [blinded condition](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Blinded) states (emphasis mine):

> **A blinded creature can't see** and automatically fails any ability check that requires sight. [...]

Meanwhile the Divination Wizard's Portent feature states (emphasis mine):

> [...]  You can replace any attack roll, saving throw, or ability check made by **you or a creature that you can see** with one of these foretelling rolls. [...]

It seems clear to me that a Divination Wizard could not use the Portent feature on another creature while the Wizard is blinded because the target would no longer be *a creature they could see*. However, I'm unsure how this applies when changing one of the Wizard's own rolls.

Can a Divination Wizard really use the Portent feature while blinded but only on their own rolls?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Yes**

There are 2 valid targets described.

1. You
2. Another creature that you can see

So, therefore the wizard can always modify their own rolls.

Comment: In addition, if the ability check requires sight, they automatically fail, and thus can't use Portent to reroll that check?

Comment: In the case of automatic failure i don't believe that a roll is made. Or, if a roll is made, the result doesn't matter. So maybe you could modify the roll but it would still fail. Automatically.

Answer (score 8):

### Yes, they can.

It says "you or a creature you can see". If you're blinded, you can't see any creatures, so the eligible subjects are just "you".

Answer (score 8):

## Yes, but only if it doesn't require sight.

If you automatically fail a roll, you do not roll said dice and then you have nothing to replace.

Otherwise you can replace your own rolls as normal.